# Angular Universal deploy to namecheap

Tags: node.js, angular, namecheap

I have angular universal application in jeans folder.
Folder structure is 
jeans/dist

> jeans > browser, server

jeans/node_modules 
jeans/src
angular.json
package.json
server.ts
tsconfig.json

##### How I make it SERVER SIDE RENDERING

I run these command in my local machine

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
npm run dev:ssr
```

##### On local Machine

I open cmd and type

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\SP\jeans>node dist/jeans/server/main.js
Node Express server listening on http://localhost:4000
```

##### Now want to host on namecheap, try a lot but no success

1. I upload all files to new directory **/jeans_demo**
2. Create a node js app with application

> root= jeans_demo
>  Application URL= newsubdomain.com.pk 
>  Startup file=server.ts 
>  OR 
> Startup file=dist/jeans/server/main.js

Also try npm install in namecheap terminal, but no got success.
facing this error when try to open domain **Error 503. Service Unavailable**